# Specify Width as 0dp with weight in android

Tags: android, textview

I have textview for which i want to use weight as well as width, but i want to pass width as 0dp, if i set width in layout params as 0, it does not render on screen.

How can i set width as 0dp dynamically through code

I even tried giving width as LayoutParams.Wrap_Content, but that also hasn't worked

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv_params_level = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the width of the TextView via xml to **0dp** you must set then its weight to **1** or other value greater than 0. To set the width programatically:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv_params_level = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0);
```

Then set this layout parameteres to your TextView:

```
tv.setLayoutParams(tv_params_level);
```

Comment: The weight doesn't have to be >= 1, it just has to be > 0. Weights of 0.5/0.25 etc are relatively common.